# Create new object based on generic type

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to create a new object based on a generic type. For example I have a couple of custom objects and I'd like to call a generic method that creates a new object based on that generic type.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Customer cust = myObject("str");
    Vendor vend = myObject("str");
    ...
}

public static <T> T myObject(String str) {
    return new T(str);
}
```

I read a couple of things about this and I know, that you can't do it like that but I just can't get it to work. For example, I've tried `type.isInstance(str)` but my editor says, that I shouldn't use that and it doesn't really work. So how should this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you want to create different types of objects
by a common generic method.
For me it smells like a bad design.

Having said that, you can achieve it in the following way:

```
public static <T> T myObject(Class<T> type, String str)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,IllegalArgumentException,
               InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException
{
    return type.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class).newInstance(str);
}
```

You see, the method above receives a `Class` argument,
so that it knows of which class the newly created object should be.
The method first gets the constructor which can accept one `String` argument.
Then you call the contructor to actually create the object.

You see, you the [`getDeclaredConstructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) and [`newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-) methods
might throw a lot of different exceptions. Therefore you would need
to handle these exceptions by some try/catch code.
(For brevity I omitted this in my code here, and simply added
a `throws` declaration.)
This raises some red flags about the design of this approach.

The method above would be used like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Customer customer = myObject(Customer.class, "str");
    Vendor vendor = myObject(Vendor.class, "str");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I agree with you, this isn't a nice way to do it. But my code has methods that do the same thing (only for different objects). And this allows me to shorten everything to a single method.